# error when using http servlet - request/response in jsp web app

Tags: jsp, jdbc, javabeans

I have a function written in Java that uses http servlets- request/response, to connect to a local database... I want to use it in a jsp file.
Please take a look at the initial portion of code below, and tell me if this can be used as it is. If it cannot be used as it is, then what kind of modifications have to be made to it.
This code should be executed after a user logs on- login uses bean/jsp... the login data is posted to the jsp page on which I want this code (below) to execute--

Code----------------------------------

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import java.sql.*;
import com.jp.windows.live.*;

public class login extends HttpServlet{
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException,IOException{
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
  Connection conn = null;
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
  String dbName = "seo_inspector";
  String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  String dbusername = "root";
  String dbpassword = "root";
 String userid="";
 String userpass="";
 String strQuery= "";
  Statement st=null;
  ResultSet rs=null;
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
  //initially we will try windows live authentication
  // only if that is successful, then we move on to next step-
  //i.e. retrieve all URLs assigned to this particular user
```

Answer (score 0):

Just map the servlet in `web.xml` on an URL pattern and let the form submit to that URL.

E.g.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

with

```
<form action="login" method="post">
```

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains a Hello World and several tutorial links (you'll really need it, this is pretty basic)